# For Loop to determine weighted average python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I'm new with Python and am having trouble crafting the correct for loop for a situation.

I have a dataframe `dfclean` that contains two columns: a restaurant star rating `"Star_Rating"` and total number of reviews `"Review_Count"`.

I want to find weighted averages for these star ratings (Star_Rating * (Review_Count / total number of reviews)) and add them to a new column called `"weightedavg"`.

Here's what I have so far along with notes of what I *think* I'm doing with each step:

```
#get total number of reviews
totalreviews = dfclean.Review_Count.sum()

#create empty list to append values to
weightedavg = []

#for loop
for row in range(len(dfclean)):
    weightedavg.append(dfclean.Star_Rating[row] * (dfclean.Review_Count[row] / totalreviews))

#make a new column in df consisting of weightedavg
dfclean['weightedavg'] = weightedavg
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame!

Comment: Sure! That allows others to know exactly what your DataFrame looks like. Lots of times, things that don't seem important are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use a for loop. You can take advantage of broadcasting to do something the following:

```
dfclean['weightedavg'] = dfclean['Star_Rating'] * dfclean['Review_Count'] / dfclean['Review_Count'].sum()
```

This is much faster than using a Python loop and is also syntactically cleaner. You can read about broadcasting in [the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [the pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html).

Comment: this did the trick, thank you! I will read the documentation on broadcasting

Comment: @piRSquared whoops didn't copy full line from interpreter - good catch!

Comment: @Jesse You are welcome. Just saw your other question and realize you are new to SO. If an answer(s) solves the problem you posted, please mark the (best) answer as accepted. This helps people know which questions still need to be worked on.